# Correctly specifying a random effect in a glmer model

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

I have a data set which includes seed set data from treatment and control plants, I want to include mean flower number as a random effect (derived from daily counts of each plant throughout the course of an experiment)(In the model: `scaled_mean_flower_number`). Seed set should, of course, be somewhat (or strongly) dependent on the number of flowers produced by an individual, and there is a good deal of variation between individuals. Individual plants are the experimental units (in the model: `plant_ID`).

Note: there is NO correlation between mean flower number and treatment, thankfully.

Though flower number was taken each day, I am using the mean flower count for each plant, and the response (`seed_count`) is not a repeated measure (it was, of course, measured once per plant at the end of the season), so nesting `scaled_mean_flower_number` in `plant_ID` seems incorrect. However, I think that I *do* need to include both, as `scaled_mean_flower_number` is a function of `plant_ID`, though I might be wrong about this.

My questions are:
1: Should I include both `plant_ID` and `scaled_mean_flower_number`, or only one or the other?
2: If I include both, what is the appropriate way to structure the random effect term?
3: Which (if any) of these are actually correctly constructed?

Thank you in advance for any help you can offer.

**Models**

```
mod1 = glmer(data=data, seed_count ~ nectar_treatment * scaled_mean_flower_number + (1 + scaled_mean_flower_number | plant_ID),  family= "poisson")

mod2 = glmer(data=data, seed_count ~ nectar_treatment + (1|plant_ID/scaled_mean_flower_number), family= "poisson")

mod3 = glmer(data=data, seed_count ~ nectar_treatment + (1|scaled_mean_flower_number), family= "poisson")

mod4 = glmer(data=data, seed_count ~ nectar_treatment + (1|plant_ID/scaled_mean_flower_number), family= "poisson")

mod5 = glmer(data=data, seed_count ~ nectar_treatment + scaled_mean_flower_number + (1|plant_ID), family= "poisson")
```

**Output** (summary(x))

```
>mod1: Error: number of observations (=90) < number of random effects (=180) for term (1 + scaled_mean_flower_number | plant_ID); the random-effects parameters are probably unidentifiable

########################################################################
>mod2: Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: poisson  ( log )
Formula: seed_count ~ nectar_treatment + (1 | plant_ID/scaled_mean_flower_number)
   Data: data

 AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
 844.5    854.5   -418.2    836.5       86 

Scaled residuals: 
 Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.96554 -0.07419  0.03030  0.05863  0.06804 

Random effects:
 Groups                             Name        Variance Std.Dev.
scaled_mean_flower_number:plant_ID (Intercept) 1.25     1.118   
plant_ID                           (Intercept) 1.73     1.315   
Number of obs: 90, groups:  scaled_mean_flower_number:plant_ID, 90; plant_ID, 90

Fixed effects:
                      Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                 2.7079     0.2662  10.173   <2e-16 ***
nectar_treatmenttreatment  -0.1310     0.3753  -0.349    0.727    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr)
nctr_trtmnt -0.700
########################################################################
>mod3: Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
Family: poisson  ( log )
Formula: seed_count ~ nectar_treatment + (1 | scaled_mean_flower_number)
Data: data

  AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  867.1    874.6   -430.6    861.1       87 

Scaled residuals: 
   Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.7063 -0.1027  0.0313  0.0582  3.7442 

Random effects:
 Groups                    Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 scaled_mean_flower_number (Intercept) 3.045    1.745   
Number of obs: 90, groups:  scaled_mean_flower_number, 88

Fixed effects:
                          Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                 2.7071     0.2721   9.948   <2e-16 ***
nectar_treatmenttreatment  -0.1162     0.3836  -0.303    0.762    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr)
nctr_trtmnt -0.700
#########################################################################
>mod4: Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: poisson  ( log )
Formula: seed_count ~ nectar_treatment + (1 | plant_ID/scaled_mean_flower_number)
 Data: data

   AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   844.5    854.5   -418.2    836.5       86 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.96554 -0.07419  0.03030  0.05863  0.06804 

Random effects:
 Groups                             Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 scaled_mean_flower_number:plant_ID (Intercept) 1.25     1.118   
 plant_ID                           (Intercept) 1.73     1.315   
Number of obs: 90, groups:  scaled_mean_flower_number:plant_ID, 90; plant_ID, 90

Fixed effects:
                          Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                 2.7079     0.2662  10.173   <2e-16 ***
nectar_treatmenttreatment  -0.1310     0.3753  -0.349    0.727    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr)
nctr_trtmnt -0.700
########################################################################
>mod5: Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
Family: poisson  ( log )
Formula: seed_count ~ nectar_treatment + scaled_mean_flower_number + (1 |      plant_ID)
   Data: data

   AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
 814.6    824.6   -403.3    806.6       86 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.16794 -0.04656  0.03795  0.07938  0.12562 

Random effects:
Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
plant_ID (Intercept) 1.879    1.371   
Number of obs: 90, groups:  plant_ID, 90

Fixed effects:
                          Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                 2.7227     0.2143  12.705  < 2e-16 ***
nectar_treatmenttreatment  -0.1901     0.3012  -0.631    0.528    
scaled_mean_flower_number   0.8789     0.1468   5.988 2.13e-09 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
        (Intr) nctr_t
nctr_trtmnt -0.693       
scld_mn_fl_ -0.061 -0.043
```

Comment: What is the clustering variable?  Is `scaled_mean_flower_number` a factor with discrete levels?  I'm having trouble understanding why you need a random effect.

Comment: @Andrew M, thanks for asking. I have the clustering variable set as treatment in models 1-3 (which is probably wrong). I have added a new model which replaces the above structure with scaled mean flower number nested within plant ID  as a random effect. Is this more appropriate?

Comment: I would suggest providing a working example that explains your data and reproduces the error/warning (see [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Reproducibility.html)). Here are a few links that may help:[1](http://glmm.wikidot.com/faq#toc27),[2](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/97834/warning-messages-from-mixed-model-glmer),[3](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/110004/how-scared-should-we-be-about-convergence-warnings-in-lme4), and [4](http://ms.mcmaster.ca/~bolker/R/misc/foxchapter/bolker_chap.html) for some worked examples (inlc. some that give the "converge" warning.

Comment: Obviously, you don't explain your experimental setup sufficiently. The grouping variables of the random effects should represent the experimental units, on which you have done repeated measurements. I'd guess that's at least the `plant_ID` in your setup. As a stab in the dark: `seed_count ~ treatment * scaled_mean_flower_number + (1 + scaled_mean_flower_number | plant_ID)` might be a sensible model. One would expect a (linear?) relationship between seed count and flower number and your treatments might change this relationship. Furthermore, the relationship might vary between different plants.

Comment: Thank you for your comments and suggestions @Roland. I have revised my question and the models. I have also added output from the models. I am no longer having convergence issues. My main concern at this point is deciding which model has the most appropriate structure.

Comment: @Stefan, thank you very much for those links. They are really very helpful!

Comment: @Andrew M, I am tempted to include `scaled_mean_flower_number` as a fixed effect in a glm, but the levels are not inherently meaningful per se, that is, they would not be repeated exactly were I to run the experiment again. Does this make sense? Or should I include flower number as a fixed effect?

Comment: I still can't tell for sure, because the data are not described in enough detail.  But the proposed models look inappropriate--you only have one observation per `plant_ID`.  I'm surprised any of them are converging. (I think that the identification, hence convergence is possible due to the mean-variance assumption of the Poisson model.)  Just because `scaled_mean_flower_number` is not fixed by design does not mean that it can't be used as a fixed effect.  "Random" covariates can be "fixed" effects with no problem whatsoever (as long as the model is not mis-specified).

Comment: On "fixed" vs "random" **regressors** (aka predictors aka covariates): http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/139957/fixed-regressors?rq=1 . (NB: the distinction between a "random effect", which is a parameter that we treat as coming from a probability distribution, and would have been less confusing if we only called it a "variance component")

Comment: Agree with @AndrewM. You should not use a mixed effects model if you have measured each plant only once. Just use the fixed part of `mod1` with `lm`.